# Gnu Scientific Library stopped working in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: c++, ubuntu-16.04, gsl

I had GSL (Gnu Scientific library) installed on my Ubuntu 14.04 and it was working fine. I then upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04 and now if I try to compile C++ code using GSL I obtain the error message

```
g++ -c FILE.cpp
In file included from FILE.cpp:1:0:
FILE.h:3:28: fatal error: gsl/gsl_matrix.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Makefile:42: recipe for target 'FILE.o' failed
make: *** [FILE.o] Error 1
```

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Did you try installing the library again?

Comment: It looks like the upgrade removed older packages; where those deprecated/obsoleted? Did you try re-installing them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The upgrade appears to have removed older packages. You will need to re-install them from the repository. The command `apt-cache search gsl` includes the following relevant packages:

```
libgsl-dev - GNU Scientific Library (GSL) -- development package
libgsl2 - GNU Scientific Library (GSL) -- library package
gsl-bin - GNU Scientific Library (GSL) -- binary package
```

Since you're doing dev work, you should install `libgsl-dev`.

Comment: Ah, I had only tried to install the gsl-bin and it did not help. installing libgsl-dev indeed solved the problem. thanks!

Comment: @JonathanLindgren Indeed. Libraries are generally offered in two "flavors", one for users, which comes in binary form for a specific platform/arch, and another for developers, in source form.