# Accessing GSL library with C

Tags: c, gsl

I have installed gsl library using *sudo apt install libgsl2* command.However when I run the following program using gcc,

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_rng.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_vector.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_matrix.h>
double x;
double nu;
int main(){
x=4;
nu=2;
double chi;
chi=gsl_cdf_chisq_P (double x, double nu);
printf("%lf",chi);
}
```

The following message is displayed when I compile using gcc -o file filename.c

```
gsl/gsl_rng.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

Have I missed any step during installation?Or is it required to use any flag during compilation?

Comment: You need to locate where gsl/gsl_rng.h is on your system, if its at non standard location, you need to specify include path in -I option, also check if you have read permisions to that file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gnu Scientific Library stopped working in Ubuntu 16.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46200312/gnu-scientific-library-stopped-working-in-ubuntu-16-04)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install the `libgsl-dev` package.

This package contains the include files necessary for your development.

If in doubt checkout the list of files in the package

```
$ dpkg -L libgsl2
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so.19.0.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgslcblas.so.0.0.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgslcblas.so.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so.19
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/libgsl2
...
just doc files and nothing more
```

And with the `dev` package you get

```
$ dpkg -L libgsl-dev
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgslcblas.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/gsl.pc
/usr/include
/usr/include/gsl
...
and all the header files here
```

That is the `dev` package gives you all the necessary headers and the static import libraries useful in case of a static build.

P.S. Do not be put off by the lack of `2` in the name of `libgsl-dev` package compared to `libgsl2`. Both would be of the same `2.x` version on your Ubuntu system or a derivative thereof.

P.P.S. There are a few more issues with your code.

The function that you are using `gsl_cdf_chisq_P()` belongs to the collection of CDF functions so you need to include `<gsl/gsl_cdf.h>`. And you need to call the function correctly as `gsl_cdf_chisq_P (x, nu)` instead of `gsl_cdf_chisq_P (double x, double nu)`.

The resulting code could look like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_rng.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_cdf.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_vector.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_matrix.h>

int main(){
    double x=0.05;
    double nu=9;
    double chicdf, chi;
    chi=gsl_cdf_chisq_Pinv (1-x, nu);
    chicdf=gsl_cdf_chisq_P (chi, nu);
    printf("ICDF[Chisquared<%d>](1 - %lf) = %lf\n" 
           "CDF[Chisquared<%d>](%f) = %lf\n",
                (int)nu,x,chi,(int)nu,chi,chicdf);
    return 0;
}
```

To compile it run

```
gcc -Wall -O2 testchisq.c -o testchisq -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm
```

It should print

```
ICDF[Chisquared<9>](1 - 0.050000) = 16.918978
CDF[Chisquared<9>](16.918978) = 0.950000
```

Comment: I installed the libgsl-dev.Following message is displayed.I'm trying to obtain the chi-square value using `gsl_cdf_chisq_P`.Isn't it an inbuilt function?I get the following message :.`GOF.c:12:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘gsl_cdf_chisq_P’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
 chi=gsl_cdf_chisq_P (double x, double nu);
     ^
GOF.c:12:22: error: expected expression before ‘double’
 chi=gsl_cdf_chisq_P (double x, double nu);
`

Comment: @Natasha You need to include `gsl/gsl_cdf.h` and call the function as `gsl_cdf_chisq_P (x, nu)`

Comment: Thank you so much for the help.But I am still facing trouble in compiling`:~$ gcc -Wall -O2 -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm GOF.c -o testchisq
/tmp/ccDByBsq.o: In function `main':
GOF.c:(.text.startup+0x15): undefined reference to `gsl_cdf_chisq_P'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
`

Comment: @Natasha Oh, try `gcc -Wall -O2 GOF.c -o testchisq -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm `. I wonder why the other order worked on my system.

Comment: Yep, In Ubuntu `--as-needed` option is prepended to `collect2` command line when called from `gcc`. On other distributions this option is omitted, so it is possible to list library names before the source file name. This is the internal mechanism. What it means is that source file name on ubuntu should be listed before the `-l` options.

Comment: Works like a charm.Unfortunately,the value of chi-square that I obtain is different from what is given in this link[http://kisi.deu.edu.tr/joshua.cowley/Chi-square-table.pdf]  Input in the code `double x=0.05;double nu=9`;Output obtained:`0`.The actual value given in the chi-square table is 16.919.I have specified the level of significance as 5%,which is `x=0.05`.Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: @Natasha what you are actually looking is the Inverse CDF function. That is what is in your table. Replace your function call with `gsl_cdf_chisq_Pinv (1-x, nu)`

Comment: Thank you:-) .I would like to know if there is a function for Kolmogorov Smrinov Test.I looked up in the manual [https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/doc/html/index.html].I couldn't find any hits.

Comment: @Natasha There are publicly available implementations of Kolmogorov Distribution based on GSL. For instance consider [YAT](http://cbbp.thep.lu.se/~jari/documents/yat/classtheplu_1_1yat_1_1statistics_1_1KolmogorovSmirnov.html) But we digress to far away from your original question.